# JS: Find out whether a class method was called from a child class using super.method()

Tags: javascript, oop, instance

Is there a way to determine how and what called the method in a base class?

Let's assume this:

```
class Base {
    myMethod() {}
}

class Child1 extends Base {
    myMethod() {}
}

class Child2 extends Base {
    myMethod() {
        super.myMethod();
    }
}

class Child3 extends Base {}

// extending another Child
class Child4 extends Child2 {}
```

If the method is not implemented in the child class or any of its parents (excluding Base), I would like to throw an error from `Base.myMethod`, for example:

```
let c1 = new Child1();
c1.myMethod(); // Method found on instance, works

let c2 = new Child2();
c2.myMethod(); // Method found on instance, calls super method (on Base), works

let c3 = new Child3();
c3.myMethod(); // No method found on instance, Base class throws an error

let c4 = new Child4();
c4.myMethod(); // No method found on instance but is found on parent (Child2), thus works
```

So basically the only time that I want to throw an error is when the Base's `myMethod` was called "directly", without any `super.myMethod()` in the call stack. Any ideas how to determine this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is an easier, better way to do this. Just declare the method `abstract`

Comment: @ControlAltDel That would be ideal but this is JS. AFAIK there is no abstract keyword (or am I wrong?).

Comment: oops ya I did think this was a Java question! Ignore what I said